# Codeigniter csv file upload fails

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, file-upload

I am trying to upload a csv file in my codeigniter application.  I'm trying to use `$this->upload->do_upload('filename')`, as shown here:

```
$config = array(
    'upload_path'   => './csvuploads/',
    'allowed_types' => 'csv',
    'max_size'      => '1024',
    'overwrite'     => TRUE
);

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if($this->upload->do_upload('filename')) 
{
//
}
```

This code validates the csv file and uploads it as well.  However, some csv files are not being properly uploaded.  I am copying data from online, pasting it into a csv file, and uploading it.

If I replace `'allowed_types' => 'csv'` with `'allowed_types' => '*'` then it works fine.  However I'm positive that I saved the file in the csv format.  This only happens when I'm copying and pasting the data from online.  What do I have to do to properly put this data in a csv file and upload it?

[Herewith i have attached both valid and invalid CSV Files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/plbhme2mgbjnoxm/AAA1tb2HowcA_dQW4VW-sAYWa?dl=0)

Comment: Can you give us a sample file that fails?

Comment: check your csv file mime type you are trying to upload and check that mime type is available in mime.php file under config directory

Comment: Dannnno, I have attahed both valid and invalid CSV files above. Kindly check it.

Comment: i think there is an issue with copy from online resources.type then test